# Finding probability distribution of a continous random variable

Tags: probability

How is the probability density function of a continuous random variable computed? For example, how is the Gaussian pdf for a continuos random variable computed? If you were the first one to come up with Gaussian pdf, how might you have done it? Could you briefly explain it using an example?

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good start would be the wikipedia pages which present the equations relating RVs, distribution functions, generating functions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you must decide what continuous probability distribution best fits your problem: normal, exponential, lognormal,...  Then you estimate the parameters of that particular distribution by taking samples from the population.  The uncertainty in the estimated parameters can also be estimated.  A good book on probability and statistics provides the details and examples; for example Dougherty's textbook Probability and Statistics for the Engineering, Computing, and Physical Sciences (Prentice-Hall).